# Problem with refrence the array back to main

Tags: java, arrays, methods, null, nullreferenceexception

I'm currently dealing with an assignment that deals with the (array of objects) concept.

to explain more I have three methods in the main: main - a method that returns an array after filling it - a method that deals with the array after it was filled.

and I have a text file called "Commands" that I read with the Class "Scanner" and the Class "File", this text file is giving me the orders I should do by reading the order from this file - for example - "FILL_ARRAY" and it should do this task by going to the method that is responsible to fill the array.

to switch between those orders I use `switch(command) { }` where `command` is the string that is holding the order from the file.

The problem is when I finish filling the array by the 1st method, I `return` the array and assign it in the array that has been created in the main then I need to send it to the second method when the `command` read the word -for example - "PRINT_ARRAY" so I should send it to the array to be printed in the second method, but the method says that the array is pointing toward a null.

I declared the array outside the `switch(command){ }` and assigned a null in it, but inside the switch I assigned the array that came from the first method in the array that I declared first, but it won't recognize it.

So the question is how do I assign the array that came from the 1st method in the array that has been created in the main so I can send it to the second method?

Example code(in java):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

 public class Question {
     public static void main (String [] args){

   //To read from file
    File cmdFile = new File ("Commands");
    Scanner readFromCmd = new Scanner (cmdFile);


       do{

      //declare the array
       String [] nameArray = null;

         //read from file
         String commands = readFromCmn.nextLine();

        //switch cases
        switch (commands){

               case "FILL_ARRAY":
                      nameArray = fillArray();
                      break;

              case "PRINT_ARRAY":
                     printArray(nameArray); //PROBLEM HERE! 
                     break;

            case "QUIT":
                  System.exit(0);                   


         }
         




 }while (true);



 }//main


public static String[] fillArray ()
{
//do task
return nameArray;
}

public static void printArray(String [] nameArray){
//do task

//PROBLEM HERE, WON'T SEE THE ARRAY AS A FILLED ONE, JUST SEE THE NULL.
//WHICH MEANS IT SILL INITIALIZED WITH NULL THAT I ASSIGNED TO THE ARRAY BEFORE THE SWITCH AND DIDN'T SEE 
//THE CHANGES 
}

}//class
```

so what should I do?
thx

Comment: You assigned null and u return it back in fillArray?

Comment: yeah, it first I assigned a null just to initialize the array, then the first method filled a new array then returned it back and re-assigned the old array with the new array that came back from the 1st method, so it should be pointing toward the new array not null.

Comment: `public static String[] fillArray ()
{
//do task
return nameArray;
}` - how does this even compile?, There is not `nameArray` in scope

Comment: I know, it's just an example so just imagine as if there was an array and I filled it and everything then I returned it.

Answer (score 0):

yall I get it why.. :)
I added the initialization of the array as null INSIDE THE WHILE LOOP!!
so every time the code goes through the loop again, it re-assign it as a null again. thank you guys for your effort, the code after fixing it:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

 public class Question {
     public static void main (String [] args){

   //To read from file
    File cmdFile = new File ("Commands");
    Scanner readFromCmd = new Scanner (cmdFile);

       //declare the array
       String [] nameArray = null;

       do{

         //read from file
         String commands = readFromCmn.nextLine();

        //switch cases
        switch (commands){

               case "FILL_ARRAY":
                      nameArray = fillArray();
                      break;

              case "PRINT_ARRAY":
                     printArray(nameArray); //PROBLEM HERE! 
                     break;

            case "QUIT":
                  System.exit(0);                   


         }
         




 }while (true);



 }//main


public static String[] fillArray ()
{
//do task
return nameArray;
}

public static void printArray(String [] nameArray){
//do task

//PROBLEM HERE, WON'T SEE THE ARRAY AS A FILLED ONE, JUST SEE THE NULL.
//WHICH MEANS IT SILL INITIALIZED WITH NULL THAT I ASSIGNED TO THE ARRAY BEFORE THE SWITCH AND DIDN'T SEE 
//THE CHANGES 
}

}//class
```